# JDBC transaction rollback failure on closed connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

Is it possible that if the connection to a db resource is lost during commit, which might lead to failed commit followed by failed rollback, the transaction is partially committed ? This appears to be happening in my case but wanted better clarity on this from the community. HibernateTransactionManager and Oracle are being used with JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 3):

No (barring a serious bug in Oracle or unless we are talking about a distributed transaction).

If a connection between the client and the database is lost, it is possible that the database never received the request to commit the transaction.  In that case, once the database discovers that the client is dead (which may take some time), the transaction will be rolled back.  If the connection is lost, it is possible that the database successfully commits but the client never gets the notification that the commit was successful.

If we're talking about a distributed transaction, it is possible that the transaction remains in doubt on one (or more) of the distributed nodes.  If that's the case, the transaction would appear in [`dba_2pc_pending`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_3002.htm#REFRN23002) on the nodes where the transaction is still pending.  But it wouldn't be partially committed on any node.

If I had to guess, if you're seeing something that is "partially committed", I'd wager that the problem is that your transaction boundaries aren't correct and that you have some code somewhere that is committing (implicitly or explicitly) where you don't expect it.

Comment: I think I have figured it out and think that partial commits are possible. An implicit commit is issued by Oracle on connection.close, hence any pending commits prior to connection getting closed will commit and the pending tasks of the transaction which couldn't be processed by the time the the connection was closed(due to db connection failure) will be ignored.

Comment: @user2599052 - If you are explicitly calling `connection.close` from your code, that would imply that the connection to the database isn't being lost-- you obviously still have it to be able to call the `close` method.  If you have code that is explicitly closing the connection when there are still additional steps that should have been part of the transaction, that's not a "partial commit", that's a bug in your application that is causing your transaction boundaries to be incorrect.

Comment: I am talking about a scenario where the connection to the database is lost(not by virtue of application code) during the commit. Now do you think "partial commit" is possible.

Comment: @user2599052 - No.  If the connection to the database is lost, the fact that the client would issue a `commit` if `connection.close` was called is irrelevant.  There would be no connection to the database at that point on which to transmit the request to commit the transaction.

Comment: I would agree with the comments from @Justin Cave, but also consider the fact that Oracle implicitly commits the transaction when a DDL is executed. So if you are executing DDLs in the transaction consider this fact too.

Comment: @JustinCave - If a connection pool is being used, then it will call connection.close when connection comes back again and hence the commit will take place and this is happening in my case.

Comment: @user2599052 - If the database connection is lost, it cannot "come back again".  The fact that the middle tier is maintaining a connection pool is irrelevant.  The transaction that was underway in the connection that was lost will be rolled back once the database finds that the connection has been lost.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer since I could find why partial commits were happening. The jdbc connection pool in use had property set on it to remove abandoned connections. On removal of such connections from the pool, close() would be called on such connections which would lead to commit of transactions which were using those connections at that time(not abandoned from application perspective). A solution would be to intercept such close calls and rollback the connection or handle appropriately